# How to create a filter on observables that will need the user to confirm it?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm using material radio button to make user able to change some data at server but i want him to confirm it in a dialog box that if the user clicks on the radio button by mistake the data wouldn't affect servers data and of course i don't want to use the browser confirm alert?
my thought was to use filter operator  of rxjs?

```
this.validForWalletPresenter.change.pipe(
  filter(()=> confirm('are you sure you want to edit?')),
  switchMap(x => {
    return <--- calling the server here --->
  })
).subscribe(x => {
  <--- handle server response here --->
});
```

**edit**

the problem with confirm is I can't customize it and it is like an alert and it is very ugly, my question is how i can create something that acts like confirm but shows my own modal and not an alert?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the browser confirm alert?

Comment: because it's very ugly and its not the angular way i think.

Comment: Why don't you show a nice looking madal like [ng-smart-modal](https://biig-io.github.io/ngx-smart-modal/) as a confirm window?

Comment: Can you explain/comment your code a bit? It's best if you can make your example generic and provide only relevant info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an implementation of what you intend to do:

You can find a demo here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ti7ecy

```
const changeResult$ = this.options.change.pipe(
  tap(change => {
    // open the dialog here
  }),
  switchMap(change => {
    return dialogResult$.pipe( // observable of dialog result
      take(1),                 // take 1 to complete the dialog stream
      map(confirmed => {
        if (!confirmed) {
          // set the value to previous value
        }
        return {confirmed, value} // combine values of two streams
      }),
      tap(result => {
        // close the dialog and set the state of radio to result of above
        this.options.value = result.value;
      })
    )
  }),
  filter(result => result.confirmed), // filter out not confirmed
  map(result => result.value)         // map to value
);

changeResult$
  .pipe(switchMap(result => {
    // send the request
  }))
  .subscribe(resp =>{
    // handle response
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can run `confirm` right inside `filter`:

```js
const { fromEvent } = rxjs; // = require("rxjs")
const { filter } = rxjs.operators; // = require("rxjs/operators")

const button = document.getElementById('button');
const click$ = fromEvent(button, 'click');

const confirmed$ = click$.pipe(
  filter(() => window.confirm("Are you sure?"))
);

confirmed$.subscribe(e => console.log("Click confirmed!"));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.3.3/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
<button id="button">Click on me</button>
```

But keep in mind that `confirm` is blocking javascript thread and is not good in terms of UX. See [MDN Notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm#Notes)